# How to stop ChromeDriver calling home?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver, seleniumbase

By "calling home" I mean: "check the latest Chrome version to refuse to work with older ones"?

This realization that Chrome Driver calls home came to us after Chrome got suddenly upgraded overnight to next major version, and within 12 ours regression tests performed in containers running for 20 days without any changes stopped working due to apparently "too old" Chrome (117 instead of the newly released 118). Neither ChromeDriver nor Chrome could have changed - they are installed in read-only containers (in root-owned folders inside the containers, while the containers themselves are run as underpriviledged users under k8s). The only problem is that these containers are for web scraping so they are unusually in our case not air-gapped (which would defeat their purpose), so such home-calling is possible.

This scenario can be reproduced in our web-scraping Python containers (`mirekphd/ml-scraper-py39-jup:20230919`).

The tell-tale error message is this:

> Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:48119
> from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 118
> Current browser version is 117.0.5938.88

Our versions:

```
selenium                          4.11.2
selenium-wire                     5.1.0
seleniumbase                      4.18.7
tbselenium                        0.7.0
undetected-chromedriver           3.5.3
webdriver-manager                 4.0.0

Google Chrome 117.0.5938.88 

ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052})
```

As seen above from inspecting the ChomeDriver version (114.0 released on 2023-05-31, see the miniature [release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/114.0.5735.90/notes.txt)), its knowledge of Chrome 118 (released on 2023-10-10) cannot possibly come from inside of the container system which was build and pushed to the Docker Hub on 2023-09-19, nearly a month before Chrome 118, unless  ChromeDriver devs had perfect foresight - to a few hours - of Chrome release cycle 5 months ahead (in May), which would likely require a time machine). Busted.

The problem started precisely at the moment when Chrome 118 was released (between two consecutive tests performed some 12 hours apart).

One heavy maintenance solution would be to block all possible IP addresses that ChromeDriver is using to establish that a newer version of Chrome was released (even before ChromeDriver was adapted to work with it!) to prevent it from calling home (stop the uncontrolled outbound connections) to be able to continue using the locally installed Chrome version, even if it's not the latest one.

Any better ideas to stop ChromeDriver calling home?

Comment: that message comes from the chromedriver executable... (it knows it's own version).   This is not "phoning home".  Depending on how you initialize the driver, though, you could be using a type of webdrivermanager which would attempt to update.  (undetected chromedriver may also do this?)  The latest versions of Selenium use a built-it webdrivermanager that updates driver + browser.  You have to set paths to those binaries explicitly to override that.  You can also set an environment variable to stop the driver from aborting when major versions don't match.

Comment: Nice hypothesis, let's try to test it... 
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 0 0 15039112 May 27 00:10 ./opt/chromedriver-114.0.5735.90/chromedriver` and `$ ls -lant $(which chromedriver)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 0 0 44 Sep 19 22:36 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver -> /opt/chromedriver-114.0.5735.90/chromedriver`
It's intact in its root-owned location (we would get a CVE if successful auto-update were possible here:) So no, the version is just as stated in the question, so `chromedriver` apparently does not know its own version, just checks the latest Chrome version... by calling home, which it should not (by default).

Comment: Trust me, the chromedriver executable is throwing that error.  It's major version is stated in the exception (118).

Comment: Barely a month has passed, the container is untouched, with the same ChromeDriver version (`114.0.5735.90`), but a new major Chrome version (119) has been released, so when ChromeDriver (or whatever does it) called home again, it came up with an updated error message to the latest Chrome version downloadable from  the remote repo: `This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 119` (not 118 as previously). I bet next month it will be 120...

Answer (score 0):

I see you have `seleniumbase` as one of your dependencies. Upgrade to the latest version of that and use this to prevent selenium from "calling home":

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(driver_version="keep")

# ...

driver.quit()
```

As long as you already have ANY version of chromedriver on your PATH, it will work with any version of Chrome. (As of today, the latest version of https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase is `4.20.1`)